# Kivymd: How to add checkbox in List item without creating custom class?

Tags: python, list, checkbox, kivymd

How can I add checkbox with MDList item? In my project I need an event as like, 'Store selected items texts in a python list after clicking a button.' It can be done easily when I create a custom class for List with checkbox (As shown in kivymd documentation).

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, TwoLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox

KV = """
<ListItemWithCheckbox>:
    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon
    RightCheckbox:
        id: cb

BoxLayout:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: scroll
            
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Save"
        on_release: app.save_checked()
"""

class ListItemWithCheckbox(TwoLineAvatarIconListItem):
    """Custom list item."""
    icon = StringProperty("android")

class RightCheckbox(IRightBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    """Custom right container."""

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(15):
            self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(
                ListItemWithCheckbox(text=f"Item {i}", secondary_text=f"Item {i+10}", icon='User_images/s.jpg')
            )
    def save_checked(self):
        mdlist = self.root.ids.scroll  # get reference to the MDList
        selected_item = []
        for wid in mdlist.children:
            if isinstance(wid, ListItemWithCheckbox):  # only interested in the ListItemWithCheckboxes
                cb = wid.ids.cb  # use the id defined in kv
                if cb.active:  # only append selected items

                    selected_item.append(wid.text)
        selected_item = selected_item[::-1]
        print(selected_item)


MainApp().run()
```

When I try to apply this thing with screen manager(for handling multiple screen) it is not  working. Can I create a list with checkbox without creating custom class for list?

NB: My requirement is, I need a list with checkbox. After selecting list item when press a button the selected item should print (or used in other purpose)

Answer (score 3):

In order to do it without custom classes, use the example at the end of the answer:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, TwoLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox

KV = """
<CB@TwoLineAvatarIconListItem>:
    IconLeftWidget:
        id: i1
        icon: "pencil" #root.icon
    IconRightWidget:
        icon: "a11.png" #this is a transparent png image of 188 bytes
        MDCheckbox:
            id: x54
            on_active:
                app.save_checked(*args,root.text,root.secondary_text,root.ids.i1.icon,root)

BoxLayout:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: scroll
            #for i in range(15)#
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello jbsidis"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Josue Carranza"
                secondary_text: "jbsidis"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            CB:
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
            
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: cm
        text: "Save"
        on_release: app.save_checked()
"""

selected_item = []
class MainAppjbsidis(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def save_checked(self,checkbox, value,a,b,c,w):
        mmm="""
            You clicked on:  Josue Carranza jbsidis
            Selected Items 4: [[<WeakProxy to <kivy.factory.CB object at 0x7efc032f4430>>], [<WeakProxy to <kivy.factory.CB object at 0x7efc032f4430>>], [<WeakProxy to <kivy.factory.CB object at 0x7efc0324d9e0>>], [<WeakProxy to <kivy.factory.CB object at 0x7efc03137b30>>]]
            """
        if value:
            print('The checkbox is active', 'and', checkbox.state, 'state')
            global selected_item
            if len(selected_item)==0:
                selected_item = []
                selected_item.append([w])
                print("\n\nYou clicked on: ",a,b,c)
                print("Selected Items "+str(len(selected_item))+": "+str(selected_item))
            if len(selected_item)>0:
                selected_item.append([w])
                print("\n\nYou clicked on: ",a,b,c)
                print("Selected Items "+str(len(selected_item))+": "+str(selected_item))
                self.root.ids.cm.text="Save "+str(len(selected_item))
        else:
            print('\n\nThe checkbox is inactive', 'and', checkbox.state, 'state')
            new_list=[]
            if len(selected_item)>0:
                for x in selected_item:
                    if x==w:
                        pass
                    if x!=w:
                        new_list=new_list+[w]
                selected_item=new_list
                
                print("\n\nNew Items: "+str(selected_item))
                
MainAppjbsidis().run()
```

Picture:

[image]

In case you don't want to have any Custom class like:

```
<CB@TwoLineAvatarIconListItem>:
    IconLeftWidget:
        id: i1
        icon: "pencil" #root.icon
    IconRightWidget:
        icon: "a11.png" #this is a transparent png image of 188 bytes
        MDCheckbox:
            id: x54
            on_active:
                app.save_checked(*args,root.text,root.secondary_text,root.ids.i1.icon,root)
```

You should use do it with:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, TwoLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox

KV = """
BoxLayout:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: scroll
            #for i in range(15)#
            TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: mm1
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
                IconLeftWidget:
                    id: i1
                    icon: "pencil" #root.icon
                IconRightWidget:
                    icon: "a11.png" #this is a transparent png image of 188 bytes
                    MDCheckbox:
                        id: x54
                        on_active:
                            app.save_checked(*args,root.ids.mm1.text,root.ids.mm1.secondary_text,root.ids.i1.icon,root)

            TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: mm2
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
                IconLeftWidget:
                    id: i1
                    icon: "pencil" #root.icon
                IconRightWidget:
                    icon: "a11.png" #this is a transparent png image of 188 bytes
                    MDCheckbox:
                        id: x54
                        on_active:
                            app.save_checked(*args,root.ids.mm2.text,root.ids.mm2.secondary_text,root.ids.i1.icon,root)

            TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: mm3
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
                IconLeftWidget:
                    id: i1
                    icon: "pencil" #root.icon
                IconRightWidget:
                    icon: "a11.png" #this is a transparent png image of 188 bytes
                    MDCheckbox:
                        id: x54
                        on_active:
                            app.save_checked(*args,root.ids.mm3.text,root.ids.mm3.secondary_text,root.ids.i1.icon,root)

            TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: mm4
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
                IconLeftWidget:
                    id: i1
                    icon: "pencil" #root.icon
                IconRightWidget:
                    icon: "a11.png" #this is a transparent png image of 188 bytes
                    MDCheckbox:
                        id: x54
                        on_active:
                            app.save_checked(*args,root.ids.mm4.text,root.ids.mm4.secondary_text,root.ids.i1.icon,root)

            TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: mm5
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
                IconLeftWidget:
                    id: i1
                    icon: "pencil" #root.icon
                IconRightWidget:
                    icon: "a11.png" #this is a transparent png image of 188 bytes
                    MDCheckbox:
                        id: x54
                        on_active:
                            app.save_checked(*args,root.ids.mm5.text,root.ids.mm5.secondary_text,root.ids.i1.icon,root)

            TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: mm6
                text: "Hello"
                secondary_text: "Two"
                icon: "pencil"
                IconLeftWidget:
                    id: i1
                    icon: "pencil" #root.icon
                IconRightWidget:
                    icon: "a11.png" #this is a transparent png image of 188 bytes
                    MDCheckbox:
                        id: x54
                        on_active:
                            app.save_checked(*args,root.ids.mm6.text,root.ids.mm6.secondary_text,root.ids.i1.icon,root)

            
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: cm
        text: "Save"
        on_release: app.save_checked()
"""

selected_item = []
class MainAppjbsidis(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def save_checked(self,checkbox, value,a,b,c,w):
        mmm="""
            You clicked on:  Josue Carranza jbsidis
            Selected Items 4: [[<WeakProxy to <kivy.factory.CB object at 0x7efc032f4430>>], [<WeakProxy to <kivy.factory.CB object at 0x7efc032f4430>>], [<WeakProxy to <kivy.factory.CB object at 0x7efc0324d9e0>>], [<WeakProxy to <kivy.factory.CB object at 0x7efc03137b30>>]]
            """
        if value:
            print('The checkbox is active', 'and', checkbox.state, 'state')
            global selected_item
            if len(selected_item)==0:
                selected_item = []
                selected_item.append([w])
                print("\n\nYou clicked on: ",a,b,c)
                print("Selected Items "+str(len(selected_item))+": "+str(selected_item))
            if len(selected_item)>0:
                selected_item.append([w])
                print("\n\nYou clicked on: ",a,b,c)
                print("Selected Items "+str(len(selected_item))+": "+str(selected_item))
                self.root.ids.cm.text="Save "+str(len(selected_item))
        else:
            print('\n\nThe checkbox is inactive', 'and', checkbox.state, 'state')
            new_list=[]
            if len(selected_item)>0:
                for x in selected_item:
                    if x==w:
                        pass
                    if x!=w:
                        new_list=new_list+[w]
                selected_item=new_list
                
                print("\n\nNew Items: "+str(selected_item))
                
MainAppjbsidis().run()
```

Picture without customer classes:

[image]

Comment: Edit: when I type "customer classes" that was a mistake, I mean "custom classes"

Comment: Thank you man. But I still getting a problem. In a realtime application I need to create list items in python file, then add all list items to the List in .kv file. Can you tell me a way for this problem please? 

NB: I am getting error while trying to add the checkbox in each list item.

Comment: Yes, if you need to move the selected items to a new screen (to a new list), you should use the "selected_item" global variable and add those selected items to the new MDList in the new Screen, remember that because it is a list, you can add those selected items with a for loop to the new screen or just save the values (instead of the widgets, which it does right now), as text plain string and then parse those in the new screen, depending on what you need to do

Comment: The line "icon: "a11.png" #this is a transparent png image of 188 bytes" is needed for having the checkbox clean and ready to use, download a png image that it should be transparent

Comment: OK, I got it. 

It would be very so kind for me if you help me to implement this in this script---------> https://github.com/Shourov1702040/hpylearners_Python/blob/main/Basic%20python/MDList%20with%20checkbox%20in%20kivymd%20python.py

Comment: I checked the link with your script, what I can see is that the script has the very initial way you've asked, I mean it has the structure of the example you gave us, but in my answer you can copy the last example in my answer, that one has the source code without custom classes and it has a function that help you to add the list of selected items into a variable called "selected_items" or please tell us how is the complete program you would like to achieve, or what or how is everything that you need the program to do? Is it like a checkout process?

Comment: Actually my problem was too ease, but couldn't make understand. After watching your techniques I have solved my problem. After all thank you for your valuable time.  This is solution of my problem-----------> https://github.com/Shourov1702040/hpylearners_Python/blob/main/Basic%20python/MDList%20with%20checkbox%20in%20kivymd%20python.py